# How to list the original commits (time and author) per file of a directory with git?

Tags: bash, git

I want to use git to list me (in `ls`-style):

- Who was the original author of that file
- When the file was created

I'm looking for a output like this:

```
File           Original Author         First Added       Commit
----------------------------------------------------------------
a.yaml            tom                  01/01/2020        1a12121
b.yaml            felix                05/01/2020        ad12257
[...]
```

Is his somehow possible with git?

Comment: Note that *files* do not *have* authors: it is *commits* that have authors, and each commit has a full snapshot of every file. So in a sense, if you made a commit, you're the author of every file in that commit, even if you didn't touch the file. What we do (e.g., in [Ted Lyngmo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64442404/1256452)) is have Git look at *every* commit, one by one, backwards, the way Git works. When we stumble across a commit where the *previous* commit *lacks* the file, and the commit *has* the file, we claim that this commit's author is the author of the file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `git log --pretty-format` and `--diff-filter=A` (`A` for added):

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "File           Original Author         First Added       Commit"
echo "----------------------------------------------------------------"

if [[ $# -eq 0 ]]; then
    # No arguments, list all in current directory
    files=(*)
else
    # Only show those supplied on the command line
    files=("$@")
fi

for file in "${files[@]}"
do
    if [[ -f $file ]]; then
        msg=$(git log --diff-filter=A --pretty=format:'%al %as %h' "$file")
        printf "%-17s %-20s %-17s %s\n" "$file" $msg
    fi
done
```

Example:

```
File           Original Author         First Added       Commit
----------------------------------------------------------------
CMakeLists.txt    ted                  2020-06-24        41b5c92
LICENSE           ted                  2019-06-25        39d3ad5
README.md         ted                  2019-06-25        0bfa2a3
TODO              ted                  2020-01-13        aaeea10
```

`--pretty-format` supports a few date formats although I couldn't find your exact format and it also supports a lot of different versions for displaying the author name.

Comment: Thanks this helped a lot! I used also `--max-count=1`, because for us it sometimes happened that a file was added, removed and added again. `--max-count=1` will not destroy the output here and will only list the last addition.